# Spring @ExceptionHandler on specific path

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to map Spring @ExceptionHandler onto a specific path?

I need to catch @Email validation exception, which is not happening inside my controller method, so I am unable to throw my exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that right solution for me is:

```
    public void method(@Valid Object o, BindingResult res){
    if(res.hasErrors()){
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```